# Wrong DateInterval using DateTime::diff (- 1 hour)

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2011-08-07');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('1970-01-01');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

$interval has:
41 years, 7 months, 5 days, 23 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds

Why there is 23 hours?

Comment: Daylight savings time?

Comment: Yes, maybe. Is there any methods to turn off daylight savings time? I need $interval to have 0 hours in this code. Zend framework 2 DateStepValidator works incorrectly because of it

Comment: This may be useful: [804571/how-to-subtract-two-dates-ignoring-daylight-savings-time-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804571/how-to-subtract-two-dates-ignoring-daylight-savings-time-in-php)